# Referencia de ensamblado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Cuando intento compilar mi solucion me aparece el siguiente emnsaje, alguien sabe como lo puedo resolver:

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error CS0234  El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'Reporting' no
>   existe en el espacio de nombres 'Microsoft' (¿falta alguna referencia
>   de
>   ensamblado?)  Reports D:\Projects2017\Fidupopular2018\PortalFiduPop\Business\Reports\ReportDefinitions.cs 19  Activo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es Microsoft.Reporting.Winform?

Comment: No lo se, es un proyecto que me compartieron

Comment: Puedes adjuntar una captura de pantalla con la linea que arroja el error?

Comment: En la ventana del explorador de soluciones (Solution Explorer) expande el nodo que dice Referencias (References), igual te falta agregar o no encuentra la referencia a alguna dll.

Comment: Esta dificil ayudarte, mira primero tienes que tener los mismos componentes instalados que el que creo el codigo, si no... buscalos en los nugets... ahora visual studio crea una carpeta packages(junto con tu archivo de sln) eliminala y despues limpa y compila la solucion esto deberia reinstalar los packages o nugets... si eso no lo arregla necesitas que la persona que hizo el codigo te diga que complementos uso, si no puedes saber eso entonces reemplazados con nugets.